# Split json line with delimiters in multiples new lines using bash

Tags: bash

I need a command to split

```
[{"hola1","hola2"},{"hola3","hola4"}]
```

and get as result

```
{"hola1","hola2"}
{"hola3","hola4"}
```

Could you help me please?

Obs: I am trying

```
sed 's/},{/\n/g' file
```

but this does not work.

Comment: why would you use bash to parse json? I suggest looking at least at python that comes built-in in any *nix together with bash, just import json and you can have painless parser; if bash is must - I can look at it later today

Answer (score 0):

You were close. You can just `sed 's/\[\|\]//g; s/},{/}\n{/g'` first remove the `[` and `]` characters, then substitute `},{` for `}<newline>{`.